# Array to Hash : words count

Tags: ruby

I have array of words and I want to get a hash, where keys are words and values are word count.

Is there any more beautiful way then my:

```
result = Hash.new(0)
words.each { |word| result[word] += 1 }
return result
```

Comment: Are you doing the Berkeley SaaS course?

Comment: Yes, I have a solution, but looking for the better versions.

Comment: if `result[word]` doesn't exist it'll throw an exception because there's no `+` for nil.

Comment: the `result` is initialized with 0, so if key doesn't exist it will be 0, not nil

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The imperative approach you used is probably the fastest implementation in Ruby. With a bit of refactoring, you can write a one-liner:

```
wf = Hash.new(0).tap { |h| words.each { |word| h[word] += 1 } }
```

Another imperative approach using `Enumerable#each_with_object`:

```
wf = words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word, acc| acc[word] += 1 }
```

A functional/immutable approach using existing abstractions:

```
wf = words.group_by(&:itself).map { |w, ws| [w, ws.length] }.to_h
```

Note that this is still *O(n)* in time, but it traverses the collection three times and creates two intermediate objects along the way.

Finally: a frequency counter/histogram is a common abstraction that you'll find in some libraries like Facets: [Enumerable#frequency](http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#frequency-instance_method).

```
require 'facets'
wf = words.frequency
```

Comment: May be simply, `str.split(" ").reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |h,w| puts h[w] += 1; h }`?

Comment: Some pinch-of-salt speed testing, ruby 2.0.0p451 on a macbook running mavericks: Declarative: `100.times { words.inject(Hash.new 0) { |h, w| h[w] += 1; h } }`: avg 1.17s. Imperative: `100.times { hist = Hash.new 0; words.each { |w| hist[w] += 1 } }`: avg 1.09s. `words` was an array of 10k random words, generation of the array alone took 0.2s avg. i.e. Imperative was about 9% faster.

Comment: Thank you for the last note about Facets.  I've re-implemented this several times now, and facets saves me the trouble of re-doing it or starting my own standard lib.  For others, you should check out Facets, it's like an extension of Ruby's standard library.

Comment: Great answer. I prefer the readability of `group_by(&:itself)`

Comment: Also, `each_with_object` fits better here than `reduce` IMO.

Answer (score 13):

Posted on a related question, but posting here for visibility as well:

Ruby 2.7 onwards will have the `Enumerable#tally` method that will solve this.

From the trunk [documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally):

> Tallys the collection. Returns a hash where the keys are the elements and the values are numbers of elements in the collection that correspond to the key.

```
["a", "b", "c", "b"].tally #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}
```

Answer (score 7):

With `inject`:

```
str = 'I have array of words and I want to get a hash, where keys are words'
result = str.split.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }

=> {"I"=>2, "have"=>1, "array"=>1, "of"=>1, "words"=>2, "and"=>1, "want"=>1, "to"=>1, "get"=>1, "a"=>1, "hash,"=>1, "where"=>1, "keys"=>1, "are"=>1}
```

I don't know about the efficiency.

Comment: According to doc of the facets method posted by tokland, `inject` is a slower.

Comment: Also, if you use `inject` and you need to return the object at the end of the block like above (`; h`), you should use `each_with_object` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
irb(main):001:0> %w(foo bar foo bar).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |w, m| m[w] += 1 }
=> {"foo"=>2, "bar"=>2}
```

as @mfilej said

Answer (score 2):

This one is elegant:

```
  words.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)
```