# How to get words frequency in efficient way with ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Sample input:

```
"I was 09809 home -- Yes! yes!  You was"
```

and output:

```
{ 'yes' => 2, 'was' => 2, 'i' => 1, 'home' => 1, 'you' => 1 }
```

My code that does not work:

```
def get_words_f(myStr)
    myStr=myStr.downcase.scan(/\w/).to_s;
    h = Hash.new(0)
    myStr.split.each do |w|
       h[w] += 1 
    end
    return h.to_a;
end

print get_words_f('I was 09809 home -- Yes! yes!  You was');
```

Comment: very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480852/array-to-hash-words-count

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works but I am kinda new to Ruby too. There might be a better solution.

```
def count_words(string)
  words = string.split(' ')
  frequency = Hash.new(0)
  words.each { |word| frequency[word.downcase] += 1 }
  return frequency
end
```

Instead of `.split(' ')`, you could also do `.scan(/\w+/)`; however, `.scan(/\w+/)` would separate `aren` and `t` in `"aren't"`, while `.split(' ')` won't.

Output of your example code:

```
print count_words('I was 09809 home -- Yes! yes!  You was');

#{"i"=>1, "was"=>2, "09809"=>1, "home"=>1, "yes"=>2, "you"=>1}
```

Comment: There's no need to use 'return', just frequency

Comment: I know but i think return makes it more easy to read and understand. maybe because i am coming from java, c++ ...

Comment: what if `frequency[word.downcase]` doesn't exist?

Comment: @AleksanderPohl This was true when you wrote it, but [ruby `2.4+` has added support for non-ascii case conversion](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10085). @アレックス That's what the `Hash.new(0)` is for: it's specifying a default value of `0`.

Answer (score 9):

```
def count_words(string)
  string.scan(/\w+/).reduce(Hash.new(0)){|res,w| res[w.downcase]+=1;res}
end
```

Second variant:

```
def count_words(string)
  string.scan(/\w+/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|w,h| h[w.downcase]+=1}
end
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def count_words(string)
  Hash[
    string.scan(/[a-zA-Z]+/)
      .group_by{|word| word.downcase}
      .map{|word, words|[word, words.size]}
  ]
 end

puts count_words 'I was 09809 home -- Yes! yes!  You was'
```

Comment: I like the Hash[] syntax :-)   +1

Comment: @christianblais I do too, but I sorta feel like I shouldn't need it in this case. In my projects, I usually add `map_hash` to `Enumerable`, which bakes together `map` and `Hash[]`.

Answer (score 3):

This code will ask you for input and then find the word frequency for you:

```
    puts "enter some text man"
text = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each { |word| frequencies[word.downcase] += 1 }
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by {|a, b| b}
frequencies.reverse!
frequencies.each do |word, frequency|
    puts word + " " + frequency.to_s 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, and ignores the numbers:

```
def get_words(my_str)
    my_str = my_str.scan(/\w+/)
    h = Hash.new(0)
    my_str.each do |s|
        s = s.downcase
        if s !~ /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/ 
            h[s] += 1
        end
    end
    return h
end

print get_words('I was there 1000 !')
puts '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [my code](https://github.com/apohllo/srx-polish/blob/master/lib/srx/polish/word_splitter.rb) that splits the text into words. The basic code would look as follows:

```
sentence = "Ala ma kota za 5zł i 10$."
splitter = SRX::Polish::WordSplitter.new(sentence)
histogram = Hash.new(0)
splitter.each do |word,type|
  histogram[word.downcase] += 1 if type == :word
end
p histogram
```

You should be careful if you wish to work with languages other than English, since in Ruby 1.9 the downcase won't work as you expected for letters such as 'Ł'.

Answer (score 2):

```
class String
  def frequency
    self.scan(/[a-zA-Z]+/).each.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word, hash|
      hash[word.downcase] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

puts "I was 09809 home -- Yes! yes!  You was".frequency