# how to convert Array to Hash: integer count

Tags: ruby

I am working on iteration: time targeting section of [this](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/eventmanager.html#iteration:-clean-phone-numbers) (the Event Manager exercise from Jumpstart Lab). I figured out how to iterate over the array and turn it into a hash from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480852/array-to-hash-words-count) thread. This is what I have:

```
require "date"

    time = ["11/12/08 10:47","11/12/08 13:23","11/12/08 13:30","11/12/08 14:04","11/12/08 14:46"]

    #makes array of all times
    time.each do |time|
        @array = Array(DateTime.strptime(time,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour)
    end


    #makes hash of :time => number of instances
     result = Hash.new(0)
      @array.each do |time|
        result[time] += 1  
      end
     puts result
```

The hash I get when I run it is `{ 14 => 1 }`, which is not what I'm looking for.  I suspect this happens because my array is made of integers, not strings like the example. Is there a way to accomplish the same effect on integers? Or do I have to convert my integers to strings? If I have to convert to strings, where do I put `to_s`?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use `time` more than once as a variable name to start with.

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to do with the hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic is incorrect:

```
time.each do |time|
    @array = Array(DateTime.strptime(time,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour)
end
```

The body of the loop is *replacing* the contents of `@array` every time, so you only get the last element when you're done.  Also, using `time` as the inner variable name is confusing (and destructive in older versions of Ruby).

What you want is to *append* to the array with `<<` inside the loop, instead of *assigning* to it with `=`:

```
@array = []
time.each do |t|
     @array << DateTime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour
end
```

But that's a very procedural way of building an array, and not very Rubyish. The idiomatic way would be to use `map` to construct the new array all at once:

```
@array = time.map { |t| DateTime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour }
```

As a side note, I'm not sure why you decided to make `@array` an instance variable.  You could just call it `array`; using `@` for arrays is a Perl thing, not Ruby.

Anyway, once you fix the creation of `@array`, your logic for building the count Hash should work as-is.  You could, however, build it in a similar way by using `reduce`; this is just one possibility:

```
result = @array.reduce({}) { |h, t| h.merge({t => h[t]+1}) }
```

You can further simplify the logic by using a built-in method of Ruby arrays called `group_by`.  This call:

```
time.group_by { |t| DateTime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour }
```

returns this Hash:

```
{10=>["11/12/08 10:47"], 13=>["11/12/08 13:23", "11/12/08 13:30"], 14=>["11/12/08 14:04", "11/12/08 14:46"]}
```

That's close to what you want in `result`; all you have to do is replace those array values with their lengths.  Fortunately, `map` works on Hashes, too, but what it returns is an array of arrays instead of another Hash, so you have to convert it back when you're done. This will do the trick:

```
result = Hash[time.group_by { |t| DateTime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour }.map{|k,v| [k, v.length]}]
```

Comment: I think you mean `t` not `time` within your .each example.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I guess I didn't understand the difference between map and each, but I looked it up and now I do. Thank you again.

Comment: @kaxla For your interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254128/arrayeach-vs-arraymap

Answer (score 1):

You could get the result with one line:

```
result = Hash[time.group_by{|str| DateTime.strptime(str,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour}.map{|k,v| [k, v.count]}]
```

***Explanation:***

*Actually, there are three steps:*

```
> step_1 = time.group_by{|str| DateTime.strptime(str,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour}
=> {10=>["11/12/08 10:47"], 13=>["11/12/08 13:23", "11/12/08 13:30"], 14=>["11/12/08 14:04", "11/12/08 14:46"]}

> step_2 = step_1.map{|k,v| [k, v.count]}
=> [[10, 1], [13, 2], [14, 2]]

> step_3 = Hash[step_2]
=> {10=>1, 13=>2, 14=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to choose the right data structure for the job. In this case, the right data structure is not a `Hash`, it is a `Multiset`. [Unfortunately, there is no `Multiset` in the standard library or the core library, but there is a `multiset` gem.]

```
require 'date'
require 'multiset'

time = [
  '11/12/08 10:47', 
  '11/12/08 13:23', 
  '11/12/08 13:30', 
  '11/12/08 14:04', 
  '11/12/08 14:46'
]

Multiset[*time.map {|t| DateTime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour }]
# => #<Multiset:#1 10, #2 13, #2 14>
```

As you can see, there is one entry at the tenth hour, and two entries each at the 13th and 14th hour.