# Create hash from array and frequency

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array `[1,2,4,5,4,7]` and I want to find the frequency of each number and store it in a hash. I have this code, but it returns `NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`

```
def score( array )
  hash = {}
  array.each{|key| hash[key] += 1}
end
```

Desired output is

```
{1 => 1, 2 => 1, 4 => 2, 5 => 1, 7 => 1 }
```

Comment: mr, some suggest using inject (aka reduce), which is fine, but all you have to do is change `hash = {}` to `hash = Hash.new(0)`. That tells Ruby that if it encounters `hash[key]` in a context where it must have a value (such as `hash[key] += 1` or `v = hash[key]`) and the hash does not contain the key `key`, it is to add `key=>0` to the hash before taking further action (such as `hash[key] += 1`).  On the other hand, `if hash[key] == 7` will evaluate to `if nil == 7` if `key` is not in the hash; `key=>0` will not be added to the hash.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Nice teaching...!! Liked it.. *+1*.

Comment: @tokland, the problem may be the same, but not the question.  Here, mr. wants to know why he got a particular error, which seems to me quite ligit.

Comment: fair enough, then let's say it's related :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480852/array-to-hash-words-count

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do as below :

```
def score( array )
  hash = Hash.new(0)
  array.each{|key| hash[key] += 1}
  hash
end
score([1,2,4,5,4,7]) # => {1=>1, 2=>1, 4=>2, 5=>1, 7=>1}
```

Or more Rubyish using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
def score( array )
  array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|key,hash| hash[key] += 1}
end
score([1,2,4,5,4,7]) # => {1=>1, 2=>1, 4=>2, 5=>1, 7=>1}
```

> The reason of why `NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass` ?

`hash = {}` is an empty has,with default value as `nil`.`nil` is an instance of `Nilclass`,and `NilClass` doesn't have any instance method called `#+`. So you got `NoMethodError`.

Look at the [`Hash::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) documentation :

```
new → new_hash
new(obj) → new_hash
```

> Returns a new, empty hash. ***If this hash is subsequently accessed by a key that doesn’t correspond to a hash entry, the value returned depends on the style of new used to create the hash. In the first form, the access returns nil. If obj is specified, this single object will be used for all default values.*** If a block is specified, it will be called with the hash object and the key, and should return the default value. It is the block’s responsibility to store the value in the hash if required.

Answer (score 25):

In Ruby 2.4+:

```
def score(array)
  array.group_by(&:itself).transform_values!(&:size)
end
```

Answer (score 19):

Ruby 2.7 onwards will have the `Enumerable#tally` method that will solve this.

From the trunk [documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally):

> Tallys the collection. Returns a hash where the keys are the elements and the values are numbers of elements in the collection that correspond to the key.

```
["a", "b", "c", "b"].tally #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}
```

Answer (score 13):

Just use inject. This type of application is exactly what it is meant for. 
Something like:

```
a.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash,word| hash[word] += 1; hash }
```

Answer (score 2):

Love me some [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

`results = array.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, arr_element| hash[arr_element] += 1; hash }`

```
1.9.3p448 :082 > array = [1,2,4,5,4,7]
 => [1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 7] 
1.9.3p448 :083 > results = array.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, arr_element| hash[arr_element] += 1; hash }
 => {1=>1, 2=>1, 4=>2, 5=>1, 7=>1}
```

Comment: That would (IMO) be cleaner with `each_with_object`: `a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }`

Comment: To each their own, @muistooshort :)

Comment: I tend to use `inject` for "iterate with feedback" situations and `each_with_object` for "iterate and collect" situations. I got tired of the `; hash` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short option that uses the Hash array initializer

```
Hash[arr.uniq.map {|v| [v, arr.count(v)] }]
```

Answer (score 1):

The point here is that `hash[1]` doesn't exist (`nil`) when it first sees `1` in the array.

You need to initialize it somehow, and `hash = Hash.new(0)` is the easiest way. `0` is the initial value you want in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the group by method:

```
arr = [1,2,4,5,4,7]

Hash[arr.group_by{|x|x}.map{|num,arr| [num, arr.size] }]
```